# Ask Chrome to process a HTTP request from a Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am looking for a way to ask Chrome to execute a HTTP request (from a string) from an App and retrieve the *final* HTTP response. I don't want to open a socket and send the HTTP request because it would require parsing the response to handle "non-terminal" responses like a `FOUND` response that requires resending a request to the indicated URI.

Maybe there is a way to open a tab, give it a request that will be processed by Chrome and simply retrieve the final result ?

Comment: You might want to change "avec" to "with." SO doesn't let me make edits that small.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply asking about [XmlHTTPRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)? From your question, that seems to be what you want. To put it another way, you haven't given any special constraints on your problem that rule out the usual approach to this problem.

By the way, in your question you mention both Chrome Apps and tabs, which generally don't mix.

Comment: Can `XmlHttpRequest` process a request from a string ? Like `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n` ? I tried with raw sockets but they don't go through the proxy :/

Comment: No, but your example is quite a bit more than a string -- it's a well-formed HTTP request that XMLHttpRequest can generate quite well. Is there something you want to do that XMLHttpRequest can't do with setRequestHeader()? If you give an example of something you want to do that XMLHttpRequest *can't* do, then you'll be more likely to get an answer that helps you.